# Cards are not displaying correctly inside of main tag

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-cards

I am currently working on a little dashboard.

I have a file named **profile.php** in which I tried to create a card with html and  css to display some values of the user.

However it seems that nothing works on properly displaying the card.. Underneath is the code I used to create the card:

```php
<main>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="container">
      <p> Username: <?= $_SESSION['username'] ?> </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Inside my css for the profile page itself the only time I am doing something with the **main** tag is this part:

```css
main {
    margin-left: 5rem;
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

To style the card for testing I use the snippet from W3Schools:

```css
.card {
  /* Add shadows to create the "card" effect */
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a deeper shadow */
.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* Add some padding inside the card container */
.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}
```

This is how it looks on the site:

[image]

However, the problem now is that despite trying everything I had in my mind which could work it just won't display the box of the card. It just prints the text on the page with no styling at all. Has this something to do with the **main** tag? Is it not possible to render box shadows or any styling related stuff? I don't believe that .. I mean why would it be that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works like you can see, maybe some css override card class (then rename card to something else), or your css isn't applied. Try to debug in dev tools.

```css
.card {
  /* Add shadows to create the "card" effect */
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a deeper shadow */
.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* Add some padding inside the card container */
.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}
main {
    margin-left: 5rem;
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="container">
      <p> Username: darby </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Ah god I made a dumb mistake.. atleast I think so.. I separated the css for the card and the css for board now and implemented the new card.css file. It works now. Guess it really did not apply for the card. Alright then!